# Rotational dynamics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I have a hard time solving this problem, going a right way about setting up the equations. What are the properties one could use in this setting to solve for the speed of change of the Radius of the two tape parts $\dot{R}(t)$ and $\dot{r}(t)$?

I am just looking for an idea how to take this on.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you start by telling how the radius relate to the length and thickness of the tape entirely deposited around the axis?

Comment: @Exocytosis So if we say that $x$ is that length then $x(t) = R(t)\phi(t)$, and then $R(t) = \frac{x(t)}{\phi(t)}$ taking the derivative $\dot{R}(t) = \frac{\dot{x}(t)\phi(t) -x(t) \dot{\phi}(t)}{\phi(t)^2} = \frac{\dot{x}(t)\phi(t) -  x(t)\Omega}{\phi(t)^2}$? assuming $\delta$ very small

Comment: You should edit the original question to explain what you have tried, rather than putting it in a comment

Comment: I would not call this dynamics, as there are no forces involved.  Is $\Omega$ a constant?